# Event listener to change a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with a submit button and would like to change the color of the button when clicked.

I have tried this in HTML:

```js
const myButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");

myButton.addEventListener("submit", function() {
  myButton.style = "background:blue"
})
```

```html
<div>
  <form id="connexion">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pseudo" />
    <button id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Go" style="background:yellow"></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

It doesn't work.
Could you tell me where the problem is?
Thanks

Comment: buttons don't have a `submit` event, forms do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change `submit` to `click` or add the eventListener to your form. Here with the the eventListener on the form:

```js
const myButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
const myForm = document.getElementById('connexion');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  myButton.style = 'background:blue';
})
```

```html
<div>
  <form id="connexion">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pseudo" />
    <button id="submitButton" style="background:yellow">Go</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the zzzzBov's comments: Buttons don't have a `submit` event.

You need to prevent the default form action when submit the form with `event.preventDefault();`. And set the style `background-color` with the button id with:

```
document.getElementById("submitButton").style = "background: blue;";
```

You can perform the `submit` event with the form id.

Something like this:

```js
const connexion = document.getElementById("connexion");

connexion.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("submitButton").style = "background: blue;";
});
```

```html
<form id="connexion">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Pseudo" />
  <button id="submitButton" type="submit" style="background: yellow;">Go</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Buttons don't have an event for submit try using `click` instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <form id="connexion"  >
            <input type="text" placeholder="Pseudo"  />
            <input id="submitButton" type="button" value="Go" style="background:yellow"></button>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and for jquery:

```
$(document).ready({
 $("#submitButton").click(function(){
      $(this).css({
          "background-color":"blue"
      });
 });
 });
```